# Issue providing security to MongoDB

Tags: security, mongodb

I have a big problem when I try to use MongoDB, with security. Yesterday I added to my MongoDB an admin user, an user for each DB, I added iptables for more security, and MongoDBs sometimes works well, but other times it doesn't works, with the message `** WARNING: You are running in OpenVZ. This is known to be broken!!!``

Then, I reinstalled MongoDB, and I did the same as before, but I received the same message, except if I started mongo with this: `mongod --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log --logappend`, but if I added `--port foo --nohttpinterface`, the process, if started, it didn't start in the background, so, if I tried to initialize my Node.JS, I was forced to close the MongoDB process. And I tried installing the MongoDB 10Gen too, but it gave me a lot of problems, so I couldn't use it.

How can I protect my MongoDB server and databases, without broke MongoDB?

Thank's advance!

EDIT:

This is the error I get with MongoDB 10gen `exception in initAndListen std::exception: locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid, terminating
Fri Apr 12 11:33:26.515 dbexit:`

Answer (score 1):

Is your VM platform OpenVZ? If so, this has been known to cause many, many issues due to the way that hypervisor does memory management. There is a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1121) about this.

I'd ask your VM provider two questions:

1) What hypervisor is your VM using

2) If OpenVZ, is it possible to move to a Xen or KVM hypervisor. I'd be surprised if they were not able to offer any alternatives to OpenVZ.

Comment: Is possible change to Xen, but is more expensive. Change to Xen would be the only solution?

Comment: I'm afraid so. Xen, as a hypervisor is much preferred. It's what I use personally.

Comment: I will try to change the hypervisor, if not, I would use the iptables for only localhost connections to MongoDB, add an admin user, and an user for the db, and encrypt the data. I hope it would be enough security.